# ATmega 328p behaving weird with a static function

Tags: static, microcontroller, arduino, avr-gcc

I'm trying to use an [ATmega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#Device_overview) 328p (Arduino Ethernet) to control a Wiznet W5100 Ethernet controller. The libraries I'm using are tested and work, but for me they don't. Here's what I tracked the problem down to:

I'm trying to read two registers, that tell me how many bytes of data have been received by the W5100:

```
uint16_t readTest() 
{
    uint16_t res = W5100.read(0x0426);
    res = (res << 8) + W5100.read(0x0427);
    return res;                                             
}
```

But even though I'm not sending any data, this function, called from main(), will return 1024 instead of 0. Now comes the weird part: If I add the static keyword like this:

```
static uint16_t readTest() 
{
    uint16_t res = W5100.read(0x0426);
    res = (res << 8) + W5100.read(0x0427);
    return res;                                             
}
```

Then the function suddently returns 0 as it is supposed to!
Also I could change it to this:

```
uint16_t readTest() 
{
    return (W5100.read(0x0426) << 8) + W5100.read(0x0427);
}
```

This must be the compiler messing with me. I really don't get it. To compile I use the standard Arduino IDE, the command looks something like this:

```
avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=22 -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SoftwareSerial -I/home/xc317/sketchbook/libraries/serlcd -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SPI -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Ethernet -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/Ethernet/utility /usr/share/arduino/libraries/Ethernet/Server.cpp -o/tmp/build1305752250561284982.tmp/Ethernet/Server.cpp.o
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: `static` allows the compiler to do more aggressive inlining. So the exact code calling `readTest()` is also important for any suggestion.
You may also have a look at the generated assembler code by dissassembling the object file using the `avr-objdump` tool.

Comment: This bug has been solved now by storing the two bytes in different uint16_t's before merging them:

    uint16_t b1 = W5100.read(0x0426);
    uint16_t b2 = W5100.read(0x0426);
    return ((b1 << 8) & 0xFF00) | (b2 & 0x00FF);